# How to make a search with jquery and the wikipedia API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, wikipedia-api

I have read a lot of posts, old, new and the wikipedia documentation.

I have this request that works itself and in the sanbox:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=einstein&format=json
- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=einstein

but when I try to use it in a javascript script, I can not get the data:

I tried both ajax and Json:

here is the code I used:

- a 'GET' request with ajax :

code markup sucks

```
function build_wiki_search_url(pattern) {
    var base_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php";
    var request_url = "?action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=";
    var url = base_url + request_url + pattern;
    return url;
}

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#doit").click(function() {
        console.log("Submit button clicked");
        var pattern = $("#search").val();
        var url = build_wiki_search_url(pattern);
        console.log(url);
    $.ajax( {
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorMessage) {
             console.log("damnn");
          }
        });
      console.log("end");
    });
 })
```

- a 'POST' request with ajax following the wikipedia documentation

  ```
    var base_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php";
    $.ajax( {
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: base_url,
        data: {
            action: 'query',
            list: 'search',
            format: 'json',
            srsearch: 'einstein',
            origin: '*',
       },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("ok");

            // do something with data
        },
        error: function(errorMessage) {
            console.log("damnn");
        }
    } );
  ```
- and a getJSON try:

  ```
  //getJSON atempt.
    console.log(url +  '&callback=?');
    $.getJSON(url + '&callback=?', function(json) {
          console.log("ok");
          });
  ```

Here is the output in my console:

```
Submit button clicked    
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=einstein
script.js 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes in fact from the html:

```
<form > 
  <input type="text" id="search"> <button id="doit"> Search!!</button>
</form>
```

Since the button is in a form, this button normal behavior is to generate a submit action. So the idea is to disable this normal behavior with:

```
$("#doit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

The full working code :

```
function build_wiki_search_url(pattern) {
    var base_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php";
    var format = "&format=json";
    var request_url = "?action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=";
    var url = base_url + request_url + pattern;
    return url;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#doit").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Submit button clicked");
        var pattern = $("#search").val();
        var url = build_wiki_search_url(pattern);
        $.ajax( {
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data.query.searchinfo.totalhits);
            },
            error: function(errorMessage) {
                 console.log("damnn");
              }
        });
    });
})
```